# getting form:options value in AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

Jsp code is as follows:

```
<form:select id="taxId" path="taxSeqNo" cssClass="defaultText"        <form:options items="${taxListItemsBean.taxList}" itemValue="key" itemLabel="label"/>
</form:select>
```

Where ${taxListItemsBean.taxList} is declared as

```
private List<KeyItemDto> taxList;
```

in the form.java class.

I want to pass this taxList through ajax to controller. Code in Ajax is:

```
//..
var options = {
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/abc.html",
                dataType : 'json',
                contentType:'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(taxList ),
                beforeSubmit: function(data,set,options) {
                    if(!confirm("xxx?")) {
                        return false;
                    }
                },

..//
```

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/abc.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView executeConfirmTaxHttpServletRequest request,
      , @RequestBody List<KeyItemDto> taxList) {

System.out.println("taxList "+taxList);

}
```

With the above code im getting a NPE in Ajax at this line :

```
data: JSON.stringify(taxList ),
```

Not sure what is wrong with the code and how would it get passed to controller and retrieved. Any inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, you want get the dropdown selected value in the ajax, then you want a make a call to Controller from the ajax.

If my understanding is right, then you have to use JQuery `.change()` function to get the selected value and then make a ajax call to server.

Below code gives the clear idea,
js code:

```
    var taxValues = [];
    $('#taxId option').each(function() { 
                taxValues.push( $(this).attr('value') );
            });
    $('#taxId').change(function(e) {
        //var taxValue = $('#taxId :selected').val(); // gives the dropdown selected value
        $.ajax({
            url: "/getTaxValue",
            data: "taxValues="+ taxValues, //passing the selected value to controller as a parameter
            success: function(result){
               alert(result);
            }
        });     
    });
```

Here we passing the selected value to controller as a request parameter, in controller you will receive this value using @RequestParam annotation.

Controller code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/getTaxValue", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getTaxValue(@RequestParam("taxValues") String[] taxValues) {

        return taxValues;
    }
```

Comment: I want the entire dropdown list not just the selected value. I was able to retrieve the selected value like you described above but couldnt get the entire dropdown list value.

Comment: JNPW, I have edited my answer to get all dropdown values in an array and pass it to the Controller, as array.